# How to return same row multiple times with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, range, overlap

My knowledge is pretty basic so your help would be highly appreciated.

I'm trying to return the same row multiple times when it meets the condition  (I only have access to select query).

I have a table of more than 500000 records with `Customer ID, Start Date and End Date`, where `end date` could be `null`.

I am trying to add a new column called `Week_No` and list all rows accordingly. For example if the date range is more than one week, then the row must be returned multiple times with corresponding week number. Also I would like to count overlapping days, which will never be more than 7 (week) per row and then count unavailable days using second table.

Sample data below

t1

```
ID     | Start_Date | End_Date
000001 | 12/12/2017 | 03/01/2018
000002 | 13/01/2018 |
000003 | 02/01/2018 | 11/01/2018
...
```

t2

```
ID     | Unavailable
000002 | 14/01/2018
000003 | 03/01/2018
000003 | 04/01/2018
000003 | 08/01/2018
...
```

I cannot pass the stage of adding week no. I have tried using `CASE` and `UNION ALL` but keep getting errors.

```
declare @week01start datetime = '2018-01-01 00:00:00'   
declare @week01end datetime = '2018-01-07 00:00:00' 
declare @week02start datetime = '2018-01-08 00:00:00'   
declare @week02end datetime = '2018-01-14 00:00:00' 
...
SELECT  
  ID,
  '01' as Week_No,
  '2018' as YEAR,
  Start_Date, 
  End_Date 

FROM t1 
WHERE (Start_Date <= @week01end and End_Date >= @week01start)
 or (Start_Date <= @week01end and End_Date is null)
UNION ALL   
SELECT
  ID,
  '02' as Week_No,
  '2018' as YEAR,
  Start_Date, 
  End_Date  
FROM t1 
WHERE (Start_Date <= @week02end and End_Date >= @week02start) 
 or (Start_Date <= @week02end and End_Date is null)
...
```

The new table should look like this

```
ID     | Week_No | Year | Start_Date | End_Date   | Overlap | Unavail_Days
000001 | 01      | 2018 | 12/12/2017 | 03/01/2018 | 3       | 
000002 | 02      | 2018 | 13/01/2018 |            | 2       | 1
000003 | 01      | 2018 | 02/01/2018 | 11/01/2018 | 6       | 2
000003 | 02      | 2018 | 02/01/2018 | 11/01/2018 | 4       | 1
...
```

Comment: what technology are you using? Is it sql server?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks

Comment: How are you defining "week number"?  Do you have a calendar table of some sort, with a list of weeks?

Comment: No I do not unfortunately, I was planning to declare dates n times

Comment: what do you mean by "overlapping days"?

Comment: 'Overlap' counts how many days Week_No 01 overlapped date range between Start_Date and End_Date.

Comment: in my answer i include start and end dates for each week, so adding 6 days will give you the start of the next week. Could be used to find the overlapping days. Don't forget to up vote or mark as answer if it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

business wise i cannot understand what you are trying to achieve. You can use the following code though to calculate your overlapping days etc. I did it the way you asked, but i would recommend a separate table, like a Time dimension to produce a "cleaner" solution

```
/*sample data set in temp table*/
select '000001' as id, '2017-12-12'as start_dt, ' 2018-01-03' as end_dt into #tmp union
select '000002' as id, '2018-01-13 'as start_dt, null as end_dt union
select '000003' as id, '2018-01-02' as start_dt, '2018-01-11' as end_dt 

/*calculate week numbers and week diff according to dates*/
select *,
DATEPART(WK,start_dt) as start_weekNumber,
DATEPART(WK,end_dt) as end_weekNumber,
case 
    when DATEPART(WK,end_dt) - DATEPART(WK,start_dt) > 0 then  (DATEPART(WK,end_dt) - DATEPART(WK,start_dt)) +1
    else (52 - DATEPART(WK,start_dt)) + DATEPART(WK,end_dt)
end as WeekDiff 
into #tmp1
 from 
        (
        SELECT *,DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, start_dt), CAST(start_dt AS DATE)) [start_dt_Week_Start_Date],
        DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, start_dt), CAST(start_dt AS DATE)) [startdt_Week_End_Date],
        DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, end_dt), CAST(end_dt AS DATE)) [end_dt_Week_Start_Date],
        DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, end_dt), CAST(end_dt AS DATE)) [end_dt_Week_End_Date]
         from #tmp
        ) s

/*cte used to create duplicates when week diff is over 1*/
;with x as
(
 SELECT TOP (10) rn = ROW_NUMBER() --modify the max you want
  OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_columns 
  ORDER BY [object_id]
)  
/*final query*/
select  --*
            ID,
            start_weekNumber+ (r-1) as Week,
            DATEPART(YY,start_dt) as [YEAR],
            start_dt,
            end_dt,
            null as Overlap,
            null as unavailable_days
             from

(
        select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by id) r
         from
        (
            select d.* from x
            CROSS JOIN #tmp1 AS d
            WHERE x.rn <= d.WeekDiff
            union all
            select * from #tmp1
            where WeekDiff is null

        ) a
)a_ext
order by id,start_weekNumber

--drop table #tmp1,#tmp
```

The above will produce the results you want except the overlap and unavailable columns. Instead of just counting weeks, i added the number of week in the year using start_dt, but you can change that if you don't like it:

```
  ID    Week    YEAR    start_dt    end_dt  Overlap unavailable_days
000001  50  2017    2017-12-12   2018-01-03 NULL    NULL
000001  51  2017    2017-12-12   2018-01-03 NULL    NULL
000001  52  2017    2017-12-12   2018-01-03 NULL    NULL
000002  2   2018    2018-01-13        NULL  NULL    NULL
000003  1   2018    2018-01-02   2018-01-11 NULL    NULL
000003  2   2018    2018-01-02   2018-01-11 NULL    NULL
```